# How do I assign an IBOutlet a value using an Initializer?

Tags: swift, init, iboutlet

I am having difficulty with something that I feel like *should* be working, I am wondering if there are some things that I'm not understanding about initializing values of IBOutlets.

So I've created a class that has three IBOutlets. I then created initializers for those outlet variables. When I create a new instance of the class and pass it hard-coded values I get **nil** in return.

So I've println()'ed the incoming settingLabel value to make sure incoming parameter indeed carries a value, it comes back as **"hello"** as to be expected. Then I attempt to assign the value to the **settingsLabel.text**, however when I call println(settingsLabel.text) comes back as **nil**.

[image]
*(Thread 1: EXV_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0))*

My Question is:

**What am I missing here and/or How do I assign an IBOutlet a value with an initializer?**

This is my call to the initializer:

```
let cell = SettingCell(settingLabel: "hello", settingSwitch: true, timeSetting: 3)
```

This is my **SettingCell.swift** class:

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var settingsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingsSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeSetting: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    init(settingLabel: String, settingSwitch: Bool, timeSetting: NSNumber) {

        println(settingLabel) // returns hello <--------------------

        super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "SwitchSettingCell")
        settingsLabel.text = settingLabel
        self.settingsSwitch.on = settingSwitch
        self.timeSetting.text = timeSetting.description as String

        println(settingsLabel.text) // returns nil <--------------------

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    var cellDelegate: SettingCellDelegate?


    @IBAction func handledSwitchChange(sender: UISwitch) {

        self.cellDelegate?.didChangeSwitchState(sender: self, isOn:settingsSwitch!.on)


    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**myStoryboard:**

[image]

Comment: the settingsLabel it is not an optional

Comment: I was playing with optionals during trouble-shooting, thanks for pointing that out, I've tested and updated the post to reflect current failing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IBOutlet` keyword is just a way to tell Xcode that the view should be visible inside your storyboard. You can connect these outlets in your storyboard, and in doing so cause the variables to be instantiated & added as subviews from the storyboard instead of in code.

In your code you are creating your cells programmatically, not from a storyboard (indeed if you tried to create them from a storyboard your app would crash, since you haven't implemented `init(coder:)`). Because of this, your variables have no reason to be "outlets" and are not ever initialised. You must initialise them yourself, add them as subviews & setup constraints, all in code.

In your initialiser, your code is ineffectual because your variables are still `nil`. In fact, in your edit, you removed the optional chaining `?`s which will have the effect of crashing your app, since the variables are force unwrapped, but are `nil`. This is the same reason `println(settingsLabel.text)` is crashing.

---

**Edit:**

Ok, so your issue is that you want to initialise your cells from the storyboard, but you're instead doing it programmatically by calling your custom initialiser. In `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`, you get your cells by dequeuing one from the reuse queue:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SettingsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingCell
```

*(This assumes you have given your cell prototype the identifier "SettingsCell" in the storyboard)*

Whenever a view is created from a storyboard, the view's `init(coder:)` initialiser is used, so you must provide an implementation of this in your `SettingCell` subclass. Once the cell has been dequeued, the cell's outlets will be initialised and added as subviews of the cell.

So after dequeuing a cell, you can setup your labels and switch:

```
cell.settingsLabel.text = //...
cell.settingsSwitch.on = //...
cell.timeSetting.text = //...
```

Comment: I've updated my post to show my storyboard, I do have connections from the labels and switches... is this the issue?

Comment: so, essentially what your saying, is that if I want to create the cells by passing them into my SettingsCell( ), I'll need to do so programmatically without using the storyboard? Also, previously I was creating the cell using dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier and casting it as a SettingCell.

Comment: Yes, you can only call a custom initialiser programmatically. For table view cells, I would strongly discourage this, and recommend you instead let the table view create them for you from the storyboard. I've edited the answer to elaborate on this.

Comment: I just read your edit.. that's what I was doing previously but I wanted to be able to pass my cellForRowAtIndexPath two different types of cells, one with a label and switch and one with two labels. This is why I started down the initialization process

Comment: I see your edit, I can revert back to my original code base, if I ask another question on stack regarding how to get two different cell types to parse would be able to take a look at it?

Comment: In that case you should be creating two different cell prototypes in your storyboard with different reuse identifiers (e.g. "SwitchCell" and "LabelCell"), and each of a different class with the appropriate outlets hooked up. You can then conditionally dequeue one or the other depending on the index path in `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`.

Comment: ok, I think this is where i had the issue which lead me to tying to initialize my class. I'll revert back and make an attempt at it again. Thank you so much for your help stuart!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it.